# SQL рассчитать дату старта (дата расчета + 5 рабочих дней)

Tags: sql

Простой вопрос, а как делать забылось - помогите пожалуйста.

У меня есть 2 таблицы:

- календарь в которой указаны даты, рабочие и выходные дни;
- таблица с датами расчета некоторых параметров.

Необходимо рассчитать **дату старта** (2я таблица) = [дата расчета + 5 рабочих дней]. Пример см ниже.

```
CREATE TABLE #Calendar(
     id DATE
    ,isWorkDay BIT
    ,isHoliday BIT  
);

INSERT INTO #Calendar(
     id
    ,isWorkDay
    ,isHoliday  
)
VALUES
     ('2022-01-14',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-15',0,0)
    ,('2022-01-16',0,0)
    ,('2022-01-17',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-18',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-19',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-20',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-21',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-22',0,0)
    ,('2022-01-23',0,0)
    ,('2022-01-24',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-25',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-26',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-27',1,0)
    ,('2022-01-28',1,0);

CREATE TABLE #Data(
     calcDate DATE
    ,startDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO #Data(
    calcDate
)
VALUES
     ('2022-01-14')
    ,('2022-01-14')
    ,('2022-01-14')
    ,('2022-01-15')
    ,('2022-01-16')
    ,('2022-01-17')
    ,('2022-01-18');

--необходимо рассчитать startDate = calcDate + 5 рабочих дней

calcDate      startDate
2022-01-14    2022-01-20  
2022-01-14    2022-01-20
2022-01-14    2022-01-20
2022-01-15    2022-01-21
2022-01-16    2022-01-21
2022-01-17    2022-01-21
2022-01-18    2022-01-24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY calcDate ORDER BY id ASC) drnk
              FROM #Data
              JOIN #Calendar ON calcDate <= id
              WHERE isWorkDay = 1 )
SELECT calcDate, id
FROM cte
WHERE drnk = 5
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c95db47f97413256d223c25cd49d992a

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!!!